# Azure WebApp Containers and AppSettings/Environment Variables

Tags: azure, docker, web-applications

I've created an **AzureWebApp** running a `docker` image.  The app starts, but it does not appear to be getting a connection string.  I've defined the connection string as an AppSetting but I am not seeing that setting passed as an environment variable.

Should I expect to see my AppSetting on the container output?  Something like

```
docker run -e CONNSTR=FOO
```

The docs imply that it should just be passed automatically, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was working all along.  I had a legit issue with authenticating against the db.  I needed some logging in the service to verify that it was getting the right connection string.

It appears that the app settings are passed to the container implicitly without showing up in the logs as an -e param.

Comment: I know you found your issue was related to something else but when I add an app setting to my web app for containers, it doesnt get added as an -e environment variable. I watch the container restart but still cant see it. Any ideas?

Comment: Same here. Custom image getting deployed from Azure Container Registry and none of the appsettings are available inside the container. They are available inside the app service but that doesn't really help.

Comment: Two years later and I'm experiencing this same problem. Haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar issues when deploying an .NET Core 2 Azure Function, which was reading settings and connection strings using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager. The root cause in my case was that ASP.NET Core introduced a new configuration API.
Find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=basicconfiguration.

Assuming you're deploying an ASP.NET Core application deployed into Web Apps for Containers, you may be running into a similar issue. Please try to the following:

a) Initialize the configuration as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

...

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

b) Read connection strings as follows:

```
configuration.GetConnectionString("StorageAccountConnectionString");
```

c) Read settings as follows:

```
configuration["ContainerName"];
```

Here is a sample configuration file for my Azure Function:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": true,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "ContainerName": "container"
    },
    "Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7071
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "StorageAccountConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I am running dotnet core 2 in the container.  I have a similar setup my app.  I feel pretty . confident . that the dotnet code is right because I am able to pass environment variables to it via docker-compose like this `environment:
      - BASE_PATH=/app
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=tcp:foo.data ...`

The app reads the connection string when running local in docker-compose and I get a different value than in my appsettings.json.

Does that make sense?